# Java HMAC returns different mac when called on same value

Tags: java, authentication, encryption, hmac

When trying to use HMAC to get a mac for validating the authenticity of a request my function always returns a different mac which means I cannot use that mac is there something I am missing?

```
private byte[] hmac(String algorithm, byte[] key, byte[] message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        System.out.println("(client) AES "+secretKeySpec);
        mac.init(secretKeySpec);
        System.out.println("(client) MESSAGE "+message);
        mac.update(message);
        byte[]res=mac.doFinal();
        System.out.println("(client) MAC "+Base64.getEncoder().encode(res));
        return res;
    }
```

algorithm key and message are always the same when I call them. With the algorithm being "HmacSHA256"

output :

```
(client) AES javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe8334
(client) MESSAGE [B@15557ab5
(client) MAC [B@4ed3db30
(client) AES javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe8334
(client) MESSAGE [B@15557ab5
(client) MAC [B@7563b5d
```

Comment: You're not using `toString()` on a Java `byte[]` array, are you?  Because strings like `[B@7563b5d` are object identifier strings, not the contents of those objects...

Comment: No, I am not I have a SecretKey that I use the getEncoded() on

Comment: @Dirac Yes, you are.  You are using the `toString()` method of a Java `byte{}` array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implicitly using the `toString()` method of Java `byte[]` arrays.

From [Oracle's Java 8 `Base64.Encoder` documentation for its `encode()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encode-byte:A-):

> ```
> public byte[] encode(byte[] src)
> ```
>
> Encodes all bytes from the specified byte array into a newly-allocated
> byte array using the Base64 encoding scheme. The returned byte array
> is of the length of the resulting bytes.
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> `src` - the byte array to encode
>
> **Returns:**
>
> A newly-allocated byte array containing the resulting encoded
> bytes.

Note that the return type is `byte[]`.

When you concatenate an object with a string, as in

```
    System.out.println("(client) MAC "+Base64.getEncoder().encode(res));
```

you use the `toString()` method to convert that object to a Java `String`.

Per the [`String` Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) (bolding mine):

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the `StringBuilder`(or `StringBuffer`) class and its append method. **String conversions are implemented through the method `toString`**, defined by Object and inherited by all classes in Java.

The `toString()` method for a Java primitive array prints the **type of the array** and then it's address.

Thus:

```
(client) MAC [B@7563b5d
```

The `[B` means "`byte[]` array" and the `@7563b5d` is likely the address (or some other JVM accounting tag) for the `byte[]` Java `Object`.

If you want to print the ***CONTENTS*** of a Java primitive array such as a `byte[]` array you need to use one of the [`java.util.Arrays.toString()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-boolean:A-).